# Regex for removing all dots after first one

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers

I need regex that would transform this input - "1.2.3.4.5.6" into "1.23456".
Of course it should work with any string provided.
So basically it should keep the first dot only and remove all dots that come after first one

Comment: What's your question?  The above is just passing your task which is off-topic.  Have you tried solving this?  What's your code?

Comment: of course i tried
do you want me send you all regexes i have tried ? 
if you dont know function for string replacement is String.prototype.replace

Comment: Your comment comes across as if you are irritated.  Perhaps you do not realize that I was simply trying to help you improve your question so it wouldn't be closed.

Comment: Here is how I would solve the problem, btw, `split()` the string on the first dot by using the limit argument, then remove all dots from the 2nd string, then join the two strings with a `.`.

Comment: i am sorry i really was irritated